# Watermark Effect On Top OF Div Element

Tags: javascript, css, watermark

Not sure if its possible but no harm asking.

I have a page which shows an invoice. There is an option to void the invoice via a button. What I want is to do create a watermark effect across the page but it has to be on top of the page content.

I tried using image and CSS background on the invoice container DIV element but that will be hidden if by the invoice content itself. Below is the CSS styles I am using for the class

```
background-image:url(/images/icons/void.png); 
background-repeat:no-repeat; 
background-attachment:fixed; 
background-position:35% 55%;
```

If anyone has any solution, either CSS or Javascript, ... it will be appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: Set that style on a `<div>` overlayed on the invoice content. Make sure the image has transparency where there is no text.

Comment: If you surround it with a div you can then just show/hide your div via your button to toggle back and forth between `display: none;` and `display: block;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple CSS

```
#voidBox {
    position : absolute;
    top : 20px; /*Change to Desired Position from top of screen*/
    left : 20px; /*Change to Desired Position from left of screen*/
    z-index : 1000; /*Sets element above everything else (only works on absolute and fixed position elements)*/
    background : url('/images/icons/void.png') no-repeat;
    display : none;
}
```

Then when the button is pressed, do some simple JS

```
document.getElementById('voidBox').style.display = 'block';
```

Comment: Thanks. Its exactly what I needed. Are there any alternative beside using void image, ie. CSS. Not sure if there is a way to rotate a text 45 degree using CSS. Anyway, thanks to all that posted here.

Comment: You can use the transform property. Not sure if all browsers support it, but most new ones should.  See the [WC3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp) site and the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-transform) site

Answer (score 3):

Using jyore's solution, I modified the CSS and HTML as shown below

```
/* CSS */
#VoidBox {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-20deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(-20deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(-20deg);
    transform:rotate(-20deg);
    font-size:200px;
    color:#CCC;
    font-weight:bold;
    letter-spacing:40px;
    position:absolute; 
    z-index:1000; 
    top:20%;
    left:15%;   
    opacity:0.5; 
    filter:alpha(opacity=50);
}

/* HTML */
<div id="VoidBox" style="display:none;">VOID</div>
```

Now I have the watermark effect over my invoice page without using any image file. Using JQuery, I displayed the DIV when an invoice is voided.

```
/* JQuery */
$("#VoidBox").show();
```

Hope this is useful for someone else.

Comment: Glad you got it working.  You can also add `-ms-transform` property for some IE support...[older IE's need a filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533014(VS.85,loband).aspx) I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my method for doing this. Basically you need to layer two divs on top of each other within a container.

My solution uses an invoice div with a content div and a void message div inside. hide the void message div unless the container has a 'void' class. It is then a simple matter to toggle the void class on the container using javascript.

My made a jsfiddle with comments to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/trafnar/etFmC/1/

Comment: JavaScript is needed for applying the "watermark" on the button press the OP is referring to.